# Creating draw in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I need to create such a picture in Processing:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihJc4.png)

Unfortunatelly I have got problem beacause my letters overlap and I got something like this:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o6HI.png)

There is my code:

```
void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000);
  background(0, 70, 100);
}
void monogram (int x, int y) {
  int los=int(random(0, 255));
  stroke(0, 185, 255, los);
  strokeWeight(5);

  // U //
  noFill();
  arc(x + 25, y + 60, 20, 20, 0, PI);
  line(x + 15, y + 20, x + 15, y + 57);
  line(x + 35, y + 20, x + 35, y + 57);

  // VV //
  noFill();
  beginShape();
  vertex(x + 35, y + 20);
  vertex(x + 55, y + 70);
  vertex(x + 75, y + 20);
  endShape();

  // V //
  noFill();
  beginShape();
  vertex(x + 55, y + 20);
  vertex(x + 75, y + 70);
  vertex(x + 95, y + 20);
  endShape();
}

void draw() {
 
  for (int y = 0; y < height / 50; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width / 70; x++) {
      int los2 = int(random(0, 4));

      pushMatrix();

      if (los2 == 1) {
        scale(-1, 1);
        translate(-width, 0);
      } else if (los2 == 2) {
        scale(1, -1);
        translate(0, -height);
      } else if (los2 == 3) {
        scale(-1, -1);
        translate(-100 , -height);
      }

      monogram(-15+80 * x, -18+50 * y);

      popMatrix();
    }
  }   
  noLoop();
}
```

do you know what am I doing bad?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a standard grid run once in setup() and not using draw().  The following source code creates a 13x12 monogram grid.  You can experiment with the width and height settings of each monogram as well as the horizontal and vertical gaps if you want to tweak this demo:

```
void monogram (int x, int y) {
  int los=int(random(0, 255));
  stroke(0, 185, 255, los);
  strokeWeight(5);

  // U //
  noFill();
  arc(x + 25, y + 60, 20, 20, 0, PI);
  line(x + 15, y + 20, x + 15, y + 57);
  line(x + 35, y + 20, x + 35, y + 57);

  // VV //
  noFill();
  beginShape();
  vertex(x + 35, y + 20);
  vertex(x + 55, y + 70);
  vertex(x + 75, y + 20);
  endShape();

  // V //
  noFill();
  beginShape();
  vertex(x + 55, y + 20);
  vertex(x + 75, y + 70);
  vertex(x + 95, y + 20);
  endShape();
}

void monogramGrid(int l, int t, int w, int h, int hg, int vg) { 
  for (int k = 0; k < 13; k++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {      
     int x = l + j*(w+vg);
      int y = t + k*(h+hg);
      monogram(x,y);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  size(1000, 800);
  background(0, 70, 100);
  monogramGrid(0, 0, 80, 60, 0, 0);
}

void draw() { 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to operate on specific element of such monogram? I need to mirror some of them and any scale or translate method didnt work properly

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by 'mirror'.  There are three elements of the monogram: one U and two V's which are clearly marked in your code.  If you want something different then of course you'll have to change the code for that element.